# Taking user input to create multiple instances of a class and update attributes

Tags: python, class, user-input

I'm fairly new to programming, so bear with me on this. I am trying to build a class that will ultimately be used similarly to a database for inventory purposes. I have built the class and it is functioning somewhat, but I need a way to take user input from the interpreter to add new instances of the class without overwriting previous instances. I also need to be able to change attributes of previously existing instances. This is what I have so far.

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, year, make, model, color, mileage):
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mileage = mileage

    @classmethod
    def from_input(info):
        return info(
            input('Year: '),
            input('Make: '), 
            input('Model: '),
            input('Color: '),
            int(input('Mileage: '))
            )
    def print_vehicle(self):
        print('Year: ', self.year)
        print('Make: ', self.make)
        print('Model: ', self.model)
        print('Color: ', self.color)
        print('Mileage: ', self.mileage)

vehicle1 = Vehicle.from_input()
vehicle1.print_vehicle()
```

This works out well, but I haven't quite gotten it as far as I need it to go. I had tried making a nested dictionary outside of the class, thinking that I could make some statements to prompt the user to modify the dictionary (adding vehicles, updating attributes), but I couldn't get the the class to iterate through the nested dictionary with the for loop. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps make a `list`?

Comment: Agree with making a list. Can you talk about what kind of input you want to give it to add or retrieve data.

Comment: The struggle I have with making a list is mapping it to each item in the database. It's very possible I don't know how exactly a list would function in this instance. I need the attributes listed in the class to be specific to each vehicle in the database. This is why I was attempting to make a nest dictionary, but I think that may have been overcomplicating?

Comment: As far as adding data, I would like to make it so that the user can add entirely new items, which I have working with the class method, but this doesn't allow the user to name the instance. If they could name the instance, they could add as many as they need. As far as retrieving data, ultimately I want the user to be able to output everything to a txt file.